# Salary negotiation : Still not convinced by the second proposition

Tags: communication, salary, negotiation

A year ago, I accepted a job offer despite the suggested salary was way under the average (`AVG-4K` a year) because :

- I was fresh out of college, with no experience
- I didn't know what was the average salary that this specific company was offering to other employees in the same situation
- I was in hurry (needed to sign a contract before my resident permit due date ends)

Anyway, I accepted.

Now it's been **a year** since I started working, and the situation kind of changed :

- I'm pretty well integrated, and get along with my teammates.
- I made my proofs (both technically and professionally) and showed quick learning capabilities.
- I demonstrated that I am not an 'average' worker, I was actually a real added value to the team.
- Our team leader is leaving, and I'm one of two remaining key employees (who have enough knowledge on our current project)

During the annual meeting with my manager, I was clear that my salary was the only weak in my current job. 
That I was hired with a very low salary and that now, I aim `AVG+4K` annually (this was the `MAX` possible salary for a 1 year experienced software engineer, and I deserve it.)

Despite all of this, and after a two steps negotiation (two back and forth suggestions), all he could offer me is a `AVG+1K` annually saying :

> this is a huge augmentation compared to your initial salary.

Is it weird if I resist, by adding a new negotiation step and saying that I'm still not convinced by your second offer ?

*PS : I told him during the first negotiation step that, despite that I wanted `MAX`, I'd accept `AVG+2K`*

Comment: Or what you are going to quit?  Seems like a very personal choice to me

Comment: You could add another round of negotiations, but ultimately you'll have to use the only card that you hold, that you'll quit if they don't come up. Are you open to some other form of compensation, like extra paid vacation or something?

Comment: `+1k` and `+4k` doesn't mean much without context, it's better to add percentages, if you even mention specifics at all (although wanting a 4x bigger raise than what you managed to get so far seems excessive, even if it is justified).

Comment: @Dukeling: He was on AVG-4k before and has been offered AVG+1k so going to AVG+4k is less than twice what he has already negotiated. That having been said he has already got +5k which is as his manager said a pretty significant increase anyway.

Comment: Depending on the value of AVG, a 5k raise after one year seems like a pretty good deal.  I don't doubt that they aren't paying what you're worth but most companies will only approve so much of an increase.  You might have better luck exploring jobs at other companies.  If you don't absolutely love your job, I would say take the raise they're offering you and then start looking elsewhere. I did this after my first year and ended up getting a 12k raise.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it weird if I resist, by adding a new negotiation step and saying that I'm still not convinced by your second offer?

You could try, but given the fact that you already did two steps on the negotiation and reached that raise I doubt a third one could change your manager's mind.

It is not uncommon that people are payed less than they could/should on their first job, due to many reasons (no salary negotiation experience, plus the reasons you mentioned and many others). I was there too, and you should try to quickly learn from it so you know how to ask for better salaries in the future.

How I see it you have two choices: You can **take the offer or you can push for a higher amount**. If you keep pushing and you don't get what you want your other option could be **quitting for a job that pays you what you want**.

For this you should be really prepared, and not just push and renegotiate. I suggest you consider other companies and try to look for jobs elsewhere if you are going to attempt pushing further.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it weird if I resist, by adding a new negotiation step and saying
>   that I'm still not convinced by your second offer ?

You can attempt to stretch out your negotiation as long as you choose.

One of several outcomes will happen

- The company will eventually stop negotiating and say "No. Our offer is firm." In that case, you'll have to decide to accept or move on to a new company
- The company will give you what you are asking for. I assume you'll quickly accept
- The company will attempt to meet you somewhere in the middle. Be prepared to quickly decide what you will be willing to settle for and what would still be worth asking for more or walking away

You need to understand whatever leverage you might have, what you will be worth elsewhere, and what you will be willing to accept - before you continue negotiating.